# Run Azure custom script extension against azure virtual machines in private subnet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I want to install some tools on an Azure virtual machine. The exe file and ps1 script are in Azure storage (Container access provided). I am aware that the Azure VM needs Internet access for the Azure Custom Script extension to work. However, is there any workaround if we have Azure VMs in private network (no internet access), to install tools on that private VM using CSE?

Comment: well, not sure what private network means, there is no such concept. did you block outgoing internet with NSG?

Answer (score 0):

Custom script extension works by connecting to the VM using the VMagent. Hence, you do not technically need internet access to push scripts via CSE. Of course, if the script has networking features that is another issue :)

Comment: Based on my understanding,  `Azure VMs in private network (no internet access)` means OP's VM does not have public IP. Azure VM needs Internet access(access storage account port 443). If VM's really does not have Internet access, we could not access the VM.

Comment: If the VM does not have public IP, the VM still can access Internet to download from storage account. Of course, it could run CSE.

Comment: The pre-requisites for running Azure CSE is to have an internet. Th port 443 on the Azure VM is kind of blocked (i.e., outgoing and incoming is restricted to specific VNET) so technically the Azure VM is not exposed to the internet. Let's say, if we configure an Apache server like Ngnix, can we have the files stored there and access them via URI over the private network?

Comment: Sorry. I was assuming you were still allowing some connectivity at least internally. Not allowing a VM to reach the web does not mean 100% everything blocked. If you use NSGs those are applied above the internal network level. So all services in Azure could still talk if on the same private network

Comment: @ManjunathRao You could not block access to Azure datacenter, on this scenario, you could use CSE to run scripts.